# How to use wp_get_attachment_metadata for thumbnails

Tags: post-thumbnails

I would like to add the right rich text snippets so that the Goole Structured Data validator will pass all the code I have. The only things missing are the sizes of the thumbnails.

This specific examples is for the thumbnails in the loop of the Wordpress homepage.

I have this code:

```
<div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                        <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); ?>">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class'=>'post_thumbnail_common', 'alt' => get_the_title() , 'title' => get_the_title() ));
echo contentnoimg(41);} else { echo content(41); } ?>
                        </div>
```

Here I want to add the following:

```
<meta itemprop="width" content="800">
<meta itemprop="height" content="800">
```

So that the final code will look something like this:

```
<div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                        <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); ?>">
<meta itemprop="width" content="<?php XXX ?>">
<meta itemprop="height" content="<?php XXX ?>">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class'=>'post_thumbnail_common', 'alt' => get_the_title() , 'title' => get_the_title() ));
echo contentnoimg(41);} else { echo content(41); } ?>
                        </div>
```

How should I put instead of  so that the image height and width will be well collected?

Here are the content and contentnoimg functions - they format the excerpt shown after the thumbnail and crop it after X characters:

```
function content( $limit ) {
    global $post;

    if( has_excerpt() ){
        $content = the_excerpt();
    } else {
      $content = explode( ' ', get_the_content(), $limit );
      if ( count($content) >= $limit ) {
        array_pop( $content );
        $content = implode( " ", $content );
        $content = wp_strip_all_tags( $content, true );
// $content .= '...<br><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="awesomebtn">'.__('Read full post','language') .'</a>';
      } else {
        $content = implode( " ", $content );
      }

      $content = preg_replace( '/\[.+\]/','', $content );
      $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content ); 
      $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    }

    return $content;
}



function contentnoimg($limit) {
     global $post;
         if( has_excerpt() ){
        $content = the_excerpt();
    } else {     
      $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
      if (count($content)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($content);
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
$content = wp_strip_all_tags($content, true);
// $content .= '...<br><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="awesomebtn">'.__('Read full post','language') .'</a>';
      } else {
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
      }   
      $content = preg_replace('/(<img.+?>)/','', $content);
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
      $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    }
      return $content;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure would be something like this.

- Check if you have a thumbnail
- Get the meta
- Add the meta data for w/h/file
- Then render the image

  ```
  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.

  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

  $size = 'full';

  $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
  $post_thumbnail_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata ( $post_thumbnail_id );
  $main_file = $post_thumbnail_meta [ 'file' ];
  $dirname = dirname ( $main_file );
  $base_url = trailingslashit ( $upload_dir['baseurl'] ) . $dirname . '/';

  // fallback to known file if the size doesn't exist
  if ( ! isset($post_thumbnail_meta [ 'sizes' ][ $size ] ) )
  {
      $size = 'full'; // use this size when we're missing data
  }

  // full is at the root, alternate sizes exist in the sizes prop
  $imgInfo = $size === 'full' ? $post_thumbnail_meta : $post_thumbnail_meta [ 'sizes' ][ $size ];
  $filename = basename ( $imgInfo[ 'file' ] );
  $width = $imgInfo[ 'width' ];
  $height = $imgInfo[ 'height' ];
  $file = $base_url . $filename;

  ?>
  <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php echo $file; ?>">
      <meta itemprop="width" content="<?php echo $width; ?>">
      <meta itemprop="height" content="<?php echo $height; ?>">

      <?php
          the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class'=>'post_thumbnail_common', 'alt' => get_the_title() , 'title' => get_the_title() ) );

          echo contentnoimg(41);
      ?>
  </div>
  <?php

  else:  // end has_post_thumbnail else

      // no thumbnail
      echo content(41); 

  endif; // end has_post_thumbnail block
  ```

Comment: Hi, thank you. It's almost good. For the height a echo seems to be missing. I added it and it works. Btw. `$file;` is not giving the full URL. How can I give the full URL to the file? You can take a look at the live site here: https://glamourina.net/en/

Comment: now the URL is fine, but the sizes are empty `<meta itemprop="width" content="">`

Comment: I think I have size "full". This is the code as it it now live: http://pastebin.com/bByt2s6G - and if I use `the_post_thumbnail( $size );` it will remove the content excerpt. So I would like to keep the part of code `the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class'=>'post ...  `

Comment: The code should take the size of the thumbnail. Doesn't matter if it is full, medium, large. In different posts, the thumbnail can be different. In old posts the size was small. I just would like to get the url, width and height. The code you gave, especially the part `<?php      the_post_thumbnail( $size );   ?>` modifies the view in front end, as well as specific image classes, alt, title of the image. Is it possible to not edit the thumbnail itself, but just collect the size of the imagefile without editing the front-end?